# Как часто писать данные?

Tags: android

Мое первое небольшое приложение. Вкратце, например: пользователь задает элемент списка. Вводит, скажем Имя(Ключ): Возраст, Вес, Рост. Добавил. В списке - имена-ключи. Щелкает по имени - в отдельном окне как-то обрабатываются значения ключа.
Хранение - обычный файл. Гуглил базы данных, написано что увеличит размер на 5Мб, а у меня не для сотен-тысяч задач, максимум на пару десятков.

Так вот: какой подход будет верным при записи-загрузке данных? Каждый раз при переходе на новую активность записывать в файл и загружать из него в новой активности? Или хранить всё в переменных до закрытия приложения?

Comment: У вас получается (если данные только вы используете в одной проге) баланс между скоростью работы и защитой от потери данных.

Comment: как вариант - использовать SharedPreferences

Comment: @rjhdby Спасибо, а вы имеете в виду: 1) Как-то добавлять новые ключи динамически? 2) Сохранять весь обьект (хешмапу) (как-то)? 3) Сохранять обьект, преобразовав его в StringSet?

Comment: зависит от логики вашего приложения. Сложно что-то советовать, не зная юзкейсов

Comment: @rjhdby В примере все как есть описано. 1 (главное) активити - список имен. 2 активити - экран заполнения полей новой задачи (имени). При заполнении полей - данные сохраняются в файл (с текстовыми разделителями, чтобы потом разбить в массив). И отправляет в главное окно. А в главном окне сразу идет чтение из файла в HashMap<String,String>, циклом построчно.

Comment: В общем, сейчас пока использую вариант 1 - добавляю ключи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждый отдельный момент времени нет смысла хранить в оперативной памяти абсолютно все данные, которые имеются для использования. Обычно везде стараются загружать данные по необходимости. В вашем случае изначально загрузили список имен, а затем при клике на имя подгружаем остальную информацию. Закрыли эту информацию -
 выгрузили из памяти. Но опять же зависит от конечного размера файла. В любом случае 5Мб накопителя не такой критический объем для смартфона, зато скорость чтения данных выше чем при работе с файлом, особенно когда он разростется. Да и оперативную память кушать нехорошо, и так уже не хватает 3 гигабайт)